# Why the java interface variables are final?

Tags: java, oop

Why the java interface variables are final?

Is there a better explanation why variables in a java interface are final by default?

Comment: You could have searched the same in some search engines first.

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about.  Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: They are public static final because the Java Language Specification (JLS) says so. Asking us to mind-read the original designers or guess why is opinion-based (even if we think we know we're 100% right).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, variables declared in an interface are *implicitly* `public` `static` and `final`.  This is not some "default" that you can override.

Why are they `final` and `static`?

1. A public static non-final interface variable:

- would be akin to a global variable, and global variables are terrible for unwanted coupling, and
- would (probably) be an abstraction leak.

2. A public non-static non-final interface variable:

- would also an abstraction leak, and
- would presents difficulties for classes that implement multiple interfaces.

The difficulties would be like the diamond inheritance problem that is reason that a Java class cannot extend more than one other class.

In short, they are implicitly `static` and `final` because the reverse would detract from Java as an OO programming language with (relatively) strong encapsulation.